# Does "exactly once semantics" in Kafka need a replication factor ≥ 3?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

From the Kafka [documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/35/documentation/streams/developer-guide/config-streams):

> Recommendation: 
> While it is technically possible to use EOS with any replication factor, using a replication factor lower than 3 effectively voids EOS. Thus it is strongly recommended to use a replication factor of 3 (together with `min.in.sync.replicas=2`). This recommendation applies to all topics (i.e. `__transaction_state`, `__consumer_offsets`, Kafka Streams internal topics, and user topics).

Can someone shine some light onto this rather vague explanation?

Is it *in principle* possible to use EOS with a replication factor < 3, no matter how ill-advised and problematic?

Or is it *strictly* impossible? And if this is so, *why?*